# PHP max_execution_time ignored (no safe mode, no shared host, just localhost/windows7/php 5.3.1 and Apache timeout is 300)

Tags: php

This problem drives me nuts, because the max_execution_time in the php.ini and in the htaccess and reported from php is definitely higher, than reportet in the warning message.

```
<?php
echo "Max execution time: ".ini_get("max_execution_time")."<br />";
while(true)
{
    sleep(1);
}
?>
```

Output:

Max execution time: 240

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\timetest.php on line 5

**Answer**

Yes, it seems to be a bug:
max_input_time overwrites max_execution_time!

htaccess:

```
php_value max_execution_time 240
php_value max_input_time 111
```

timetest.php:

```
<?php
echo "Max execution time: ".ini_get("max_execution_time")."<br />";
echo "Max input time: ".ini_get("max_input_time")."<br />";
while(true)
{
    sleep(1);
}
?>
```

Output (proof):

Max execution time: 240

Max input time: 111

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 111 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\timetest.php on line 6

Thanks for the help!

Comment: one question about your question. i used to think, that maximum execution time which shows browser is set by browser, and it can differ from the value in php.ini! did i think wrong?

Comment: @Syom - max_execution_time is not set by browser, it is the php.ini value. Browsers do have their own time-outs (to stop malicious scripts), but they are irrelevant in this scenario. The php.ini value can differ in browser and from the command line because apache uses a different php.ini than the command line mode.

Comment: @pinaki so if i saw the message "Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded" , that means that 60 seconds were set in php.ini in apache?

Comment: @Syom - Yes, if you see so in the browser. If you see the message at the command line, it's the php.ini for the php client.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a PHP bug. Reported here http://bugs.php.net/48949

Edit: Found that [max_input_time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) over-writes the max_execution time. This must be the issue with you.

Comment: Seems like the 5.3.1 version had this issue/bug. Will be fixed with 5.3.1. http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49868&edit=1