# Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 555

Tags: php, web-crawler

I'm trying to web crawling in php using simple_html_dom.php (API)
but when i crawl the big websites ,it show error like this

```
Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\simple_html_dom.php on line 555
```

i used these codes `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` and `set_time_limit(0);` to avoid Maximum execution time error .

but it is not working !

please help me ! how to crawl for long time !

Comment: is your script hosted somewhere or do you run it locally/on your own server?

Comment: check PHP.ini of your config.

Comment: check this anwer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506538/php-max-execution-time-ignored-no-safe-mode-no-shared-host-just-localhost-win

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a shared hosting? Almost all hosting companies do not allow you to change ini variables. If not try to change max_execution_time directly from php.ini